# Should I still prevent caching of pages with an Address Field?

Tags: 7, caching, entities, users

On the [Address Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/addressfield) module page it says there can be problems with Drupal‘s cache and anonymous authors:

> Address Field should work on any entity type, but if you use it on an entity type that can be created or edited by anonymous users (such as a user account field present on the registration form), you should ensure pages where the form is present are not cached by Drupal. Drupal's core page caching and its AJAX form refresh used by this module do not work together.
>
> The recommended solution for now is to use the [Cache Exclude](https://drupal.org/project/cacheexclude) module to tell Drupal which pages not to cache, such as user/register.

So I should prevent that pages get cached which allow anonymous users to enter an address.

I tried to find out more about this problem and found the issue [Prevent Drupal from caching pages with forms that include an address field widget](https://www.drupal.org/node/1861608). In [comment #14](https://www.drupal.org/node/1861608#comment-8690909) it says that this issue is resolved in Drupal 7.27 (because of the fix to [SA-CORE-2014-002](https://www.drupal.org/SA-CORE-2014-002)).

Now I wonder if the linked issue is about the quoted problem (and the project page could remove this advice), or if I should still prevent caching for these pages (maybe for some other reason not talked about in that issue)?